# How to get Heart Rate values from Google Fit History?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-fit

I need to get all the heart rate measurements, and not the minimum, maximum and average, which is what I have been able to get.

This is the code I use for reading from my java class.

Thank you!

```
private void readDataFitnessHistory()
{
    // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
    Log.d(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.d(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            // The data request can specify multiple data types to return, effectively
            // combining multiple data queries into one call.
            // In this example, it's very unlikely that the request is for several hundred
            // datapoints each consisting of a few steps and a timestamp.  The more likely
            // scenario is wanting to see how many steps were walked per day, for 7 days.
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
            // Analogous to a "Group By" in SQL, defines how data should be aggregated.
            // bucketByTime allows for a time span, whereas bucketBySession would allow
            // bucketing by "sessions", which would need to be defined in code.
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query and await the result of
    // the read request.
    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    DataSet dataSet = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM);
    showDataSet(dataSet);
    displayBpmDataForToday();


}
```

The response:

```
History:    Type: com.google.heart_rate.summary
History:    Start: 22 sept. 2017 10:40:06
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    End: 22 sept. 2017 10:40:06
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: average Value: 71.13179
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: max Value: 86.0
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: min Value: 55.0
```

Comment: Does TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM (beats per minute) no what you asking for?

Comment: If so, but what I need is to get all the measurements in the indicated time range, and not the minimum, maximum and average, of the indicated time range.

Comment: I don't think it's not yet possible. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types) stated, you may only use the `com.google.heart_rate.summary` data type to get the average, maximum, and minimum beats per minute for a time interval.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I think you're right, but I've seen that you can extract the data by data cubes, but I don't know what is the minimum period for which you can group that data.(.bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS))

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I think you're right, but I've seen that you can extract the data by data cubes, but I don't know what is the minimum period for which you can group that data.

(.bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)) 

would be the maximum period of 1 hour or could it be set in minutes?

(.bucketByTime(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

I've tried it, but it always returns me a bucket of at least one hour interval.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

In order to obtain all the datapoints of the readings made with Google Fit Api, the object DataRsult to build would be as follows:

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
.read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
.read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
.enableServerQueries()
.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.build();
```

It would return all datapoints within the specified range.

Comment: Is it necessary to specify .enableServerQueries() ? As I am new to working with google-fit, I wanted to know it.

Comment: I have tried this and I'm getting " com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user" when trying to get heart rate.However I have added BODY_SENSORS permission on manifest. Any idea to fix it?