# Access data from multiple Google Fit API Android users from android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

How can I access the data (HeartRate, steps, ...) of several users through Fit API for Android? My application displays a user list in an activity and selecting one of them should display the Google Fit history data (HeartRate, steps, ...). How could you do it?

The Google History query was made according to this post: [View Google Fit API History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425694/how-to-get-heart-rate-values-from-google-fit-history)

I build the client according to the Google Fit API documentation [(Example for user logged in the terminal)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicSensorsApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basicsensorsapi/MainActivity.java), which would only be valid for users logged in through the terminal, my requirement would be to use the login data of each user through a web server and with those credentials register me in the google fit store server to collect the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history), you may check the [Responsible use of Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview#responsible_use_of_google_fit) for best practices when managing user data.

> As a developer of fitness and wellness apps, you often collect and manage important user information. Keep these key principles in mind:
>
> - Always clearly explain to the user what data you will collect and why.
> - Honor user requests to delete their data.
> - If you read fitness data from Google Fit, you must also write the fitness data you collect to Google Fit.
> - Do not use Google Fit APIs for non-fitness purposes, such as storing medical or biometric data, selling data, or using data for advertising.
> - Carefully review the [Google Fit Terms and Conditions](https://developers.google.com/fit/terms) before using Google Fit.
>
> By using the API, you agree to the Google Fit Terms and Conditions.

Also be noted that a set of authorization scopes to request user permission to work with fitness data. Google Fit requires user consent to access fitness data.

> [**Permissions and user controls**](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview#permissions_and_user_controls)
>
> Google Fit requires user consent before apps can read or store fitness data. Google Fit defines OAuth scopes that map to three permission groups with separate read and write privileges: activity, location, and body. Each permission group grants apps access to a set of data types. Apps specify one or more of these scopes to work with fitness data, and Google Fit requests the corresponding permissions from the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but don't specify me if having all the users' permissions it is possible to access this information of the group of users from android environment or from an API hosted in a web service.