# is there anyway to get heart rate from smart watch without builds an application for the watch?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, tizen, heartrate

we want to build an android application to get heart rate data and access the sensors on it and get data over Bluetooth in java , please can any one help ?

watch used : Samsung classic s3 work in tizen.

m.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer. As far I know, u can`t directly get data from sensors without installing app on the watches, but u can get it from Google Fit or some other applications(If its API allows it)
[How to get Heart Rate values from Google Fit History?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425694/how-to-get-heart-rate-values-from-google-fit-history)