# Google fit api heart rate android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-fit, google-fit-api

Is it possible to fetch heart rate in android studio thanks google fit api? I have tried to catch data like step using fitnessOptions and than using Fitness.getHistoryClient.

Can I catch heart rate in the same way or ther's something else to do?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425694/how-to-get-heart-rate-values-from-google-fit-history

Comment: I have tried that code, but it's not complete. I don't understand how to display the data

Comment: Try workaround on this post stackoverflow.com/a/63784803/3057100